# Query wp_usermeta

Tags: sql, wordpress

my code seems to display only users who has filled out some information in the field. If a field is missing, then it will not display any other info about the user.

Here is my current code:

```
 
select m1.user_id as userid, m1.meta_value as firstname, m2.meta_value as lastname, m3.meta_value as email, m4.meta_value as phone, m5.meta_value as rolle, m6.meta_value as pw

from wp_usermeta m1

join wp_usermeta m2 on (m2.user_id = m1.user_id and m2.meta_key = 'user_general_last_name')

join wp_usermeta m3 on (m3.user_id = m1.user_id and m3.meta_key = 'user_general_email')

join wp_usermeta m4 on (m4.user_id = m1.user_id and m4.meta_key = 'user_general_phone')

join wp_usermeta m5 on (m5.user_id = m1.user_id and m5.meta_key = 'user_general_role')

join wp_usermeta m6 on (m6.user_id = m1.user_id and m6.meta_key = 'user_general_pw')

where m1.meta_key = 'user_general_first_name'
```

Result:
[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lljy.png)

However, i would like to also display the other users who might be missing something i some fields. I am totally newbie when it comes to work with sql and database, please be specific. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use LEFT join instead of inner

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Perfect!